# ADB passing parameter value to activity

Tags: android, adb

The below code takes the text field value and compares it to open the windows. I wanted to pass the parameter value from the command line

```
jakhar.aseem.diva;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HardcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /* access modifiers changed from: protected */
    @Override // android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity, android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hardcode);
    }

    public void access(View view) {
        if (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.hcKey)).getText().toString().equals("vendorsecretkey")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Access granted! See you on the other side :)", 0).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Access denied! See you in hell :D", 0).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I used the below command and was not successful

```
adb shell am start -n jakhar.aseem.diva/.HardcodeActivity --es "hckey" "vendorsecretkey"
```

I got the below error when I run the command:

```
$ adb shell am start -n jakhar.aseem.diva/.HardcodeActivity --es "hckey" "vendorsecretkey"
Starting: Intent { cmp=jakhar.aseem.diva/.HardcodeActivity (has extras) }

Exception occurred while executing 'start':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=jakhar.aseem.diva/.HardcodeActivity (has extras) } from null (pid=2845, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10105
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityTaskSupervisor.java:1047)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:975)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:665)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1201)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1173)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUserWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:2926)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:562)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:193)
        at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:8620)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:950)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:834)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:5106)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2498)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1184)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1143)
```

I tried pair like --ei instead of --es but still same error.

The below screenshot showing the exact activity of the window and it is exported to true to call from anywhere

[image]

Please help me to pass the parameter value through adb

Comment: Sorry but I don't see anything on your screenshot that indicates the activity has set `exported=true`. Check the activity entry in `AndroidManifest.xml` and add missing `exported=true` there.

Comment: does `adb shell am start -n jakhar.aseem.diva/.HardcodeActivity` without extras work?